# Android theme customization

Tags: android, themes, styles

I am working on theme-ing my android app. After I went through '**Styles and Themes**' in Android SDK and this [article](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/), I am still left with one question.

Simply put, how can I use `android:textSize` to be `14 dip` for one `TextView`, while `18 dip` for another `TextView`, inside a `Theme`?

I know how to do this with styles. I can define two different styles and make the two different TextViews to use those styles.

What I find difficult is how to do this with Theme. A theme lets me define let's say `android:textSize`, but then it's applicable to all the `TextView` s in all the layouts of the `Activity`.

Any idea how to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you plan to differentiate the TextViews?

Comment: they will have different "android:id"s.

Comment: well, you just set the font size directly on each view, that will override any setting in the theme. Styles are there to group /common/ attributes together. When your text views use different font sizes, then that's not a common attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with creating a style, for instance, "subtext", and apply the subtext style to multiple elements. Check out the links I posted in this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973928/how-to-make-theme-of-application-configurable-by-user/3680841#3680841